# Pointing out a single dot with text input

Tags: python, plot, bokeh, word2vec

i want to plot my gensim-word2vec model in kind of a "word-galaxy"(like here: http://www.anthonygarvan.com/wordgalaxy/) and flashing out a single dot by entering it's name in a search field and pressing a submit-button. I'm fairly new to all this python-stuff and so i actually don't understand the curdoc documentation or the example here: https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/tree/master/examples/app/movies. This is my code:

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file, show, ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.models.widgets import TextInput
from bokeh.models import HoverTool
from gensim.models import word2vec
from sklearn.manifold import TSNE

model = word2vec.Word2Vec.load_word2vec_format('GoT.model.vector', binary=True) #load the trained model. (Game of Thrones script)

ts = TSNE(2)
vectors, words, x, y = []
form word in model.vocab:
    vectors.append(model[word]) #append my vector to "word"
    words.append(word) #append my word
reduced_vecs = ts.fit_transform(vectors)
for vec in reduced_vecs:
    x.append(vec[0])
    y.append(vec[1])

search_word=TextInput(title="Search")
source = ColumnDataSource(data = dict(x=x,y=y,words=words))
hover=HoverTool(tooltips=[("word", "@words")]

p = figure(plot_height=600, plot_width=800, title="word2vec", tools=[hover], logo=None)
p.circle('x','y', radius=0.1, source=source, line_color=None)

show(p)
output_file('plot.html', mode="cdn")
```

Can you help me with this? Thank you,
FFoDWindow

Comment: `curdoc()` is mostly only relevant for **Bokeh Server Applications**. But you are creating a static, standalone HTML file using `output_file` so it should not really be needed. However, one problem you definitely have is that you need to call `output_file` **before** you call `show`. The `output_file` call is what tells `show` where and how to show things, so it has to be first.

Comment: OK, thank you for that, i'll try it later!