# How to change the color of a glyph using callback?

Tags: javascript, python, callback, bokeh

I've tried around using Bokeh, and now I want to search a word and change the color of its glyph. My code looks like that:

```
import bokeh.plotting as bp
from bokeh.models import HoverTool, CustomJS
from bokeh.models.widgets import TextInput
from bokeh.io import vform

words = ["werner", "herbert", "klaus"]
x=[1,2,3]
y=[1,2,3]
color = ['green', 'blue', 'red']
word_input= TextInput(value="word", title="Point out a word")

source = bp.ColumnDataSource(data= dict(x=x,y=y,words=words, color='color'))
hover= HoverTool(tooltips=[("word", "@words")])

# output to static HTML file (with CDN resources)
bp.output_file("plot.html", mode="cdn")

# create a new plot with the tools above, and explicit ranges
p = bp.figure(plot_height = 600, plot_width = 800, title="word2vec", tools=[hover], logo =None)
# add a circle renderer with vectorized colors and sizes
p.circle('x','y', radius= 0.1, color = color, source=source, line_color=None)
callback= CustomJS(args=dict(source=source), code ="""
    var data = source.get('data');
    var glyph = cb_obj.get('value')
    words = data['words']
    colors=data['color']
    for (i=0; i< words.length;i++){
        if(glyph==words[i]){colors[i]='yellow'}        
    }
    source.trigger('change');
""")
layout = vform(word_input, p)
# show the results
bp.show(layout)
```

This code just doesn't work, and I can't figure out why not.

What am I doing wrong? I've posted [an other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37049640/pointing-out-a-single-dot-with-text-input) earlier that day and this is kind of a first step solving it.

Comment: It would be helpful if you can describe any errors you are having other than "this code just doesn't work"

Comment: Hey, i got no Errors. My Plot is totally fine and the HoverTool works. The only issue is this `word_input`. I klick it and nothing happens. Maybe the Problem is hidden in my `callback` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

there are a couple of problems you have:

- you create the `CallbackJS` but never set is as the callback property of the `TextInput`
- you set the `color` key of data dict to the string `"color"` not to the list of colors
- you passed the actual list of colors as the `color` argument to `figure` (it should be the string name of the data source column you want to use, e.g. `"color"`)

---

Here is a version that works:

```
from bokeh.io import vform
from bokeh.models import HoverTool, CustomJS
from bokeh.models.widgets import TextInput
from bokeh.plotting import output_file, figure, show, ColumnDataSource

output_file("plot.html")

words = ["werner", "herbert", "klaus"]
x, y = [1,2,3], [1,2,3]
color = ['green', 'blue', 'red']

source = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(x=x, y=y, words=words, color=color))

hover = HoverTool(tooltips=[("word", "@words")])

p = figure(plot_height=600, plot_width=800, title="word2vec", tools=[hover])
p.circle('x','y', radius=0.1, fill_color='color', source=source, line_color=None)

callback = CustomJS(args=dict(source=source), code="""
    var data = source.get('data')
    var value = cb_obj.get('value')
    var words = data['words']
    for (i=0; i < words.length; i++) {
        if ( words[i]==value ) { data.color[i]='yellow' }
    }
    source.trigger('change')
""")

word_input = TextInput(value="word", title="Point out a word", callback=callback)

layout = vform(word_input, p)

show(layout)
```

Comment: Thanks, i appreciate your answer!

Answer (score 0):

Updated @bigreddot's solution to work under Bokeh 2.2.3 if others come along similar tasks.

```
from bokeh.layouts import column
from bokeh.models import HoverTool, CustomJS
from bokeh.models.widgets import TextInput
from bokeh.plotting import output_file, figure, show, ColumnDataSource

output_file("plot.html")

words = ["werner", "herbert", "klaus"]
x, y = [1,2,3], [1,2,3]
color = ['green', 'blue', 'red']

source = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(x=x, y=y, words=words, color=color))

hover = HoverTool(tooltips=[("word", "@words")])

p = figure(plot_height=600, plot_width=800, title="word2vec", tools=[hover])
p.circle('x','y', radius=0.1, fill_color='color', source=source, line_color=None)

callback = CustomJS(args=dict(source=source), code="""
    var data = source.data;
    var value = cb_obj.value;
    var words = data['words'];
    for (var i=0; i < words.length; i++) {
        if ( words[i]==value ) { data.color[i]='yellow' }
    }
    source.change.emit();
""")

word_input = TextInput(value="word", title="Point out a word")

word_input.js_on_change('value', callback)

layout = column(word_input, p)

show(layout)
```